# quickblox JS push for android and ios

Tags: javascript, android, ios, push-notification, quickblox

i sucessfully register Android device for GCM channel, and can see it from admin panel in Subscriptions section.

And i create a push from admin panel, and it send sucessfully, but i never recive it.

{"notification":{"registration_ids":["371f9f6af962c76eb342d7b15f4b542f07952c6a"],"delay_while_idle":false,"data":{"message":"Тест","collapse_key":"event4580541"},"time_to_live":86400},"log":[{"device_token":null,"created_at":"2015-11-21T14:22:52Z","delivered_at":null,"failed_at":"2015-11-21T14:22:52Z","error_code":null,"error_description":"Unable to deliver notification --------, received error (Failed to deliver to all recipients. Errors: InvalidRegistration.)"}]}

Any ideas?

Registration over apns channel for IOS, QuickBlox report an error {"errors":{"client_identification_sequence":["is invalid"]}}

But i bet that i provide correct token from previous steps.

Any ideas? how to get PUSH to work from JS on IOS and Android platform?

Comment: it give the an error on com.quickblox.simplesample.messages D/QBASDK:     POST https://api.quickblox.com/session.json
com.quickblox.simplesample.messages D/QBASDK:     signature=5a93832588073e78e2f339e4311e88fca1cccc59
https://api.quickblox.com/session.json?...signature=5a93832588073e78e2f339e4311e88fca1cccc59
...
com.quickblox.simplesample.messages D/QBASDK:     '{"errors":{"base":["Unexpected signature"]}}'

Comment: Plz, Any one? i also send report to QB support, with no responce.

Comment: Hello I am also facing the same issue.Did any got any updates for the same?